# Js event does not work in the Elementor plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I am writing an extension for the WordPress media library, I need to add a button to the media library, by clicking on which a modal window will open from where the user can select a picture.

See the screenshots

- [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsb5n.jpg)
- [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BTE1.jpg)

At the moment, the event does not fire when the button is clicked when the library is open when editing the page with the Elementor plugin.
JS file is included as follows

```
public function registerAssets()
{
    //add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'scripts']);
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'scripts']);
}

public function scripts()
{
    wp_register_script( 'cbi-index-js', SCRIPTS_URI . 'index.js', [ 'elementor-frontend' ], '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('cbi-index-js');
}
```

Everything works as it should in the admin area, but in Elementor the problem is probably in the namespace.

JS file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
  $('#db-upload-btn').on('click', function (e){
      alert(111)
  })
})
$('#db-upload-btn').on('click', function (e){
    alert(222)
})
console.log(333)
```

As you can see, I also output console.log (333) to the console and when I reload the page, being in the Elementor panel, 333 is output to the console, which indicates that the file has connected, but why the handler does not work when I click on the button yet I can figure it out.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

please repalce all of "**$**" character in your code with "**jQuery**" and try again!

Comment: I replaced it, but nothing has changed, for example, in the admin panel, by clicking on this button, the event is triggered. I don’t understand how Elementor works at what moment or on what hook this script needs to be connected for the event to work.

Comment: Can you please send me the link of that page?

Comment: Its localhost. The js file is 100% connected, being on the editing page, if opened the source code of the page, then this file will be displayed there and it is correctly connected.